# How to search a date in timestamp datatype in MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

I have a timestamp datatype in my column. (**Example Data:** 12/4/2013 8:57:10 PM) How can I make a query to on my timestamp column using this format. **12/4/2013** to execute all information within that row. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is easier when you use the default date format `YYYY-MM-DD`

```
select * from your_table
where date(date_column) = '2013-04-12'
```

Comment: I tried this. no error. but there is no result too.

Comment: this is correct. I got it. hahaha! i'm just sticking with slash format on date I did not notice the dash on separating the dates. and my officemate tell it too. heheh! Thank you so much.